# django import project.app vs import app

Tags: python, django, import

I am going through another django tutorial and I noticed for the imports the author uses
from **project.app.file import item** but this doesnt work unless I do
**from app.file import item**

Example:
Authors version:

**from ecomstore.catalog.models import Product**

which doesnt work 
 Error: ImportError: No module named catalog.models

but this does

**from catalog.models import Product**

I am just why the authors version doesnt work for me and why and if there is a setting I can change to fix this so its easier to follow along.

I am seeing this as an issue in following along and trying to understand how django works this and where the settings or configurations for this resides where I can change within my project.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the date, I think you're using newest django 1.4, which has a new layout when you typed "django-admin.py startproject" and "django-admin.py startapp".

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/releases/1.4/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py

Answer (score 1):

`from catalog.models import Product` is fine, and i think it's better than the example. Because if you want to use the app, you have to change every single import statement where you use your project name. Don't do `from myproject.myapp.models import MyModel`, it's a bad practice, if you're sure that the models you importing is in the same directory, i think this one is the best : `from models import Product`, else `from myapp.models import MyModel`

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I will keep just changing what the author has to this.